# Apacke Tika: how to extract page number from a pdf file?

Tags: text, pdfbox, apache-tika

I have problems with some code, can someone help me by giving me direction?

Comment: What code? Please be specific. Add expected and actual results to your post. Add error messages. Add the relevant code. Please edit your post, don't add comments. And: [welcome to Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [You may also want to take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have tweaked you post for English issues.  Please edit your post and include your code so far.